# How would I call this function from within another function?

Tags: python, tkinter

Im working on a project based off of the [following example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7546050/python-tkinter-changing-the-window-basics) that I was shown.
The buttons in the example call

```
 lambda: controller.show_frame(PageTwo)
```

to change the window or "frame", but I need to call this from within another function, not from a button, and I keep getting an error. The following is a cheesy "activation checker"

```
def KeyCheck(key_input,controller):
    import tkinter.messagebox
    if key_input in ["18806-47599-37423", "188064759937423"]:
        controller.show_frame(PageTwo)
        print ("good")
    else:
        tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Invalid Key", "They key entered is not valid for activation.")
```

But trying to call back to this "controller" no longer works. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Can you post your code. its difficult to see how your `KeyCheck` relates to linked answer.

Comment: Do you get a full traceback?  If so, what is the error?  Can you post the _full_ thing here in your question?  That can often be super helpful in debugging these things.

Comment: The whole thing is a little over 200 lines, and Im not exactly sure what all is relevant and or required. perhaps a better question that separates my specific function is  such: " how would I call the first snippet from within any function? If I added a function to the example, and all I wanted that fuction to do is run something along the lines of the first snippet above, how would I write the line that does so? If youd still like my code I can try to figure out how to reduce it down

Comment: the specific error is NameError: global name 'controller' is not defined, but even if I try to bring in controller as one of the parameters, it still doesnt work

Comment: How do you call `KeyCheck`?

Comment: from a button in tkinter, where command=Keycheck(<key entered>)

Comment: In the code you posted, there is no variable named `PageTwo`. Is that a function? A global variable?

Comment: Its in the example (your example)